# How can I search for a file by date in Kubuntu?

Tags: kubuntu, search, dolphin

I believe that an earlier version of Dolphin enabled one to search for a file by date. This facility seems to have gone. If I wanted to to search for a Libre Office writer file modified last August,say, but had completely forgotten the file's name, I would enter *odt and a dialog box would offer me the opportunity to narrow the parameters to files modified between 1/8 and 31/8, and return a few files. Now the search will return hundreds of files. Admittedly it is quick to sort by date, but the list takes much longer to create.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use kfind. The KDE team removed the integration with kfind sometime last year I beleave.

I found a solution in kubuntuforums on how to create a service menu. If you do it this way you will find the "Search with kFind" in the action menu, when you right click on a folder.

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Service
X-KDE-ServiceTypes=KonqPopupMenu/Plugin,inode/directory
Actions=searchWithKfind;

[Desktop Action searchWithKfind]
Name=Search with Kfind
Icon=system-search
Exec=kfind %u
```

Save the above text as ~/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/kfindhere.desktop (for specific users) or
/usr/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/kfindhere.desktop (for all users, I have not tried this)

My source is [here](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?55843-Re-integrate-Kfind-with-Dolphin-in-Kubuntu-11-10&p=274885&viewfull=1#post274885) and the whole thread is [here](http://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php?55843-Re-integrate-Kfind-with-Dolphin-in-Kubuntu-11-10)

Answer (score 0):

If you are not opposed to using the command line, you could use something like

```
find -iname "*.odt" -mtime -133 -mtime +102
```

to find all odt fies modified that were modified less then 133 days ago, but more than 102 days, which for toady is just files modified in August.